# Вертикальные названия столбцов DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, header

Здравствуйте. Вывожу в таблицу значения из базы данных. И некоторые из этих значений являются битовыми(1 или 0), и чтобы название столбца не занимало столько места в ширину, можно ли как-нибудь названия некоторых столбцов записывать вертикально? Использую `DataGridView`, можно и `ListView`, это не принципиально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `DataGridView` вешаем на событие `CellPainting` следующую обработку (параметры отрисовки можно менять - цвет, толщина, шрифт и т.д.):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex < dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(270);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.FormattedValue?.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 5);
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
        e.Handled = true;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 50;
    }
}
```

В конструктор формы добавить строку (чтобы высота колонки менялась):

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
```

В результате будет как-то так (заранее у колонок задал Width = 25 в визуальном редакторе):
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот [такое](http://csharpdotnet2012.blogspot.ru/2012/02/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html) решение, которое нужно повесить на событие Cell PaintingЖ

```
 StringFormat l_objformat = new StringFormat();

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {
                Rectangle r2 = e.CellBounds;
                r2.Y += e.CellBounds.Height / 2;
                r2.Height = e.CellBounds.Height / 2;
                e.PaintBackground(r2, true);
                e.PaintContent(r2);

               //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
  Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle (e.ColumnIndex, true);
                Size titleSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font);

  if (this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight < titleSize.Width)
                    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = titleSize.Width;

                rect.X += e.CellBounds.Width/2;
                rect.Y +=dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight/2;
                l_objformat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Red, rect, l_objformat);
                e.Handled = true;//This is required, else the original painting of the data grid view overwrites the changes.
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, боком он рисует, но неровно. Я сам пытался искать что-то похожее. Видимо WinForms не просчитали то, что такое свойство должно быть встроено заранее.